# Is it possible to take a break from Islam just to get a better notion about this world and maybe islam too?

Tags: imaan

Is there something in Islam that gives a believer a time to think about this world and Islam, to travel, to speak with people from all religions and all cultures, to gather information from the deepest secrets from many stems on this planet?

In this time the muslim will stop praying, do forbidden things according to Islam but with precaution (e.g. I won't drink alcohol till I get into a coma), and will be open to everything the cultures will provide for him/her to eat or drink.

Because I have done a lot of correct things my father taught me since I was a child without really believing in it for 10 years straight. Since that time I've noticed that there little to no muslims in the western hemisphere that fully obey the Quran and the hadiths mentioned in Buchari and Muslims. E.g. muslims that listen to non-muslim music, even in my own family, family members who married with non-muslims who did some things that are prohibited before their marriage, muslims who take loans with riba with them knowing it. And litteraly I don't want to be a semi-muslim. I just want to be a good muslim or just not a muslim but still have respect for the religion. I just need to take time to fully obey to Allah if he exists and make sure that Islam isn't an idea created by men.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

Islam is not a job that one could take a break from, so either one could be into Islam and be called a Muslim or if one leaves (we seek refuge in Allah from) would be murtadd (apostate).Such freethinking could take one out of the fold of Islam leaving no Eman in heart or leading to hypocrisy.

> يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُوا۟ ٱدْخُلُوا۟ فِى ٱلسِّلْمِ كَآفَّةً
>   وَلَا تَتَّبِعُوا۟ خُطُوَٰتِ ٱلشَّيْطَـٰنِ ۚ إِنَّهُۥ لَكُمْ عَدُوٌّ
>   مُّبِينٌ 
>    **O you who have believed, enter into Islam completely [and
>   perfectly] and do not follow the footsteps of Satan. Indeed, he is to
>   you a clear enemy**.(2:208)

We must enter into Islam fully. Shaitan is our enemy, he whispers such thoughts creating false ideologies and make them pleasing in minds **"I will mislead them and I will create in them false desires… (4:119)** .But thief does not enter an empty house and similarly shaitan enters in a heart with Eman and tries very hard to steal the Eman with his tricks.

You mentioned *litteraly I don't want to be a semi-muslim* for that try to be in good companionship. Talk to an imam of a Masjid or a Scholar with whom you could discuss such issues and seek advice. Start learning deen, search for a good study and dhikr circle and you could resolve such issues in the guidance of Quran, Sunnah and Ahlullah.

You mentioned *Since that time I've noticed that there little to no muslims in the western hemisphere that fully obey the Quran and the hadiths mentioned in Buchari and Muslims.*

One must not try to judge Islam by Muslims and their acts and followings. Our Deen is from Quran and authentic Sunnah, no one is accountable for other's deeds. You are questionable for your own deeds but one must try to rectify with love and wisdom specially if family is involved in disobedience. For more about why Islam islam is true http://seekershub.org/podcast/names/why-islam-is-true/

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: My sincerest apologies that you had to answer my improvident question. I'll eliminate and I'll need to learn feel less compassionate about others even though they are family. I thank you from the bottom of my heart. I've apologized too Allah too in my salats and continue to do so.

Comment: Salam no apologies May Allah Tala increase you Eman and showers his mercy and grace to you and your family.

Answer (score 0):

An analogy would answer your question.

What would your wife say if you said wanted to fool around with other women to find out if you really loved her?

Comment: First of all I don't have a wife. I'm not ready for that kind of engagement. And second of all analogies aren't answers. They give just a concept to think ultimately get to answer. So I'll be waiting for an answer.